# In typescript/javascript, what does passing an object into an if statement check do?

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

For example:

```
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (element) {
      this.myList.push({label: element.service.name, value: element.serviceId,
        service: element.service.name, typeOfService: element.typeOfService.name});
    }
  });
```

Is it a null check?
Because in that case it's redundant here, right?

Comment: Why would it be redundant?

Comment: Nah you still would need to check because of maybe this array: [null, {}, null, {}]

Comment: "Because in that case it's redundant here, right?" — We can't tell if it is redundant. We don't know what the type of `data` is. e.g. It might be `SomeObject[]` or it might be `SomeObjectOrNull[]`.

Comment: the if will check for a truthy value (a value that can be considered true)

Comment: It checks if the element can be converted to a truthy value, preventing it from blowing up if the element is not there

Comment: @Ivar I'm a java programmer, I'm not used to seeing null elements in a list.

Comment: So if I want to add to this if statement, would this do the trick: `if(element !== null && (other conditions here) {} `

Comment: @mal Also in Java many collections (including many List implementations) can contain `null` values. As a matter of fact, when you create a non-primitive array in Java, by default all the values are `null`.

Comment: As others have pointed out, `if (element)` is not necessarily the same as `if (element !== null)`. If you don't want to change the existing behavior, use `if (element && (other conditions))`.